# Performance tune tSQL Query count(*) & subqueries

Tags: t-sql, count, subquery

I know that there's a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish here.  Though the query works I fear it's performance will suffer as the dataset's it is applied to grow.

I don't even necesarily need someone to rewrite what I have if they would just be willing to point me in the direction of the topic I should study I would greatly appreciate it.

What I'm trying to return with this query is a count of the number of records at or above a certain status.

Thanks in advance for your help!

`SELECT
       ( SELECT  count(*)
         FROM TABLE1 c1 
         WHERE (  c1.U_KEY3 NOT LIKE 'z%' AND (c1.U_KEY1 = '' or c1.U_KEY1 IS NULL)  )
       ) AS 'STATUS is EMPTY'
    ,
       ( SELECT  count(*)
         FROM TABLE1 c1 
         WHERE ( c1.U_KEY3 NOT LIKE 'z%' AND LEFT(c1.U_KEY1,2) >= '70' )
       ) AS 'STATUS > 70'
    , 
       ( SELECT  count(*)
         FROM TABLE1 c1 
         WHERE ( c1.U_KEY3 NOT LIKE 'z%'  AND LEFT(c1.U_KEY1,2) >= '50' )
       ) AS 'STATUS > 50'
    , 
       ( SELECT  count(*)
         FROM TABLE1 c1 
         WHERE ( c1.U_KEY3 NOT LIKE 'z%' AND LEFT(c1.U_KEY1,2) >= '30' )
       ) AS 'STATUS > 30'
    , 
          ( SELECT  count(*)
         FROM TABLE1 c1 
         WHERE ( c1.U_KEY3 NOT LIKE 'z%' AND LEFT(c1.U_KEY1,2) >= '10' )
       ) AS 'STATUS > 10'`

Comment: Do you have any indices on `TABLE1`?  The query might run faster than you think.

Comment: How many rows are in the table? have you tried to use JOIN instead of sub-query?

Comment: @Tim the U_KEY fields are indexed.  Only 1200 rows in the table right now & it runs well enough, but there is the potential for it to grow to up 100,000.

Comment: @FLICKER haven't tried a join. Are you saying join the table to itself?

Comment: I am prepared to be wrong here, but I don't see much room for improvement.  A `COUNT` query has to scan all records retained after the `WHERE` clause, and you are really doing this in 5 different queries.  But for 100K records are you really concerned about performance?  How often do you expect to run this query in production?

Comment: You could try writing a single query with a complex `CASE` statement, but I also don't think this would be faster.

Comment: The query creates a data source I'm using in a chart as part of a dashboard.  Not sure exactly how many times it will be used in production. Doing the dashboard development as a consultant. I thought about using CASE  statement.  Will look into that again. Ty! @Tim

Comment: @jer_bear, Yes, I meant use self join 5 times

Answer (score 3):

You could roll all the subqueries into a single query using a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN c1.U_KEY1 = '' OR c1.U_KEY1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS IS EMPTY',
    SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(c1.U_KEY1,2) >= '70'           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS > 70',
    SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(c1.U_KEY1,2) >= '50'           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS > 50',
    SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(c1.U_KEY1,2) >= '30'           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS > 30',
    SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(c1.U_KEY1,2) >= '10'           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS > 10'
FROM TABLE1 c1
WHERE c1.U_KEY3 NOT LIKE 'z%'
```

But this might not run as fast as the individual subqueries.

Comment: This should be faster because there's only a single table/index scan. If there's an index with U_KEY1 and U_KEY3, it would be a single index scan with some stream aggregates. That's not terrible, depending on the size of those two columns.

Comment: @siride I knew it would be a single table scan but the `CASE` statements looked seriously heinous to me.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: They are, but they are just expressions that can be computed pretty quickly. The query is probably parallelizable also.

Answer (score 2):

I would turn the question around like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Id INT, U_Key1 VARCHAR(4) null);

INSERT INTO @t (id,U_Key1)
VALUES
(1,null),
(2,'902'),
(3,'452'),
(4,'401'),
(5,'103'),
(6,'359'),
(7,'335'),
(8,'772'),
(9,'143'),
(10,'222'),
(11,'664'),
(12,'992'),
(13,'122'),
(14,'332'),
(15,'421'),
(16,'622'),
(17,'982'),
(18,'1234'),
(19,null),
(20,'012');

WITH A AS (
    SELECT CAST(LEFT(U_Key1,2) AS INT) val FROM @t
), limits AS (
    SELECT  10 limitval, 'Status >= 10' limittext
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  30 , 'Status >= 30'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  50 , 'Status >= 50'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  70 , 'Status >= 70'

), Counts AS (
    SELECT 'Status is empty' Limittext, COUNT(id) Count FROM @t 
    WHERE U_Key1 IS null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT l.limittext, COUNT( A.val) Count FROM A
    CROSS JOIN limits l
    WHERE A.val >= l.limitval
    GROUP BY l.limittext
    )
    SELECT * FROM Counts
```

That produces the result:

```
Status is empty 2
Status >= 10    17
Status >= 30    12
Status >= 50    6
Status >= 70    4
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks @PeterO